# 2 клиента Oracle

Tags: oracle

Я установил 11 клиент Oracle на ПК, на котором был установлен 9 клиент, соответственно программа, использующая 9 клиент, перестала работать.
Использовать 9 клиент необходимо, т.к. программа работает на 9 базе.
Подскажите, можно ли иметь 2 клиента на 1 машине?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще 11 клиент отлично соединяется с 9 базами. вопрос лишь в том, возможно ли подключить к тому приложению библиотеки 11 клиента и возможно поправить строку соединения.

Если это не помогает и 9 клиент у вас на машине остался в отдельной папке, то перед запуском приложения необходимо установить переменную окружения `ORACLE_HOME` указывающую на папку с требуемым этому приложению клиентом. Так же, в редких случаях, может потребоваться прописать необходимые папки с библиотеками в PATH или LD_LIBRARY_PATH (для unix систем)